$f(x) = \log_{10} x + 3^x - 3^{\frac1x}.$ Find $m$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2|x-m| + 1}) + f(x^2 - 2x + 2) = 0$ has precisely 3 distinct solutions.

$f(x) = \log_{10} x + 3^x - 3^{\frac1x}.$ Find all values of $m$ such that the equation $f(\frac{1}{2|x-m| + 1}) + f(x^2 - 2x + 2) = 0$ has precisely 3 distinct solutions.

Here's what I got so far:
$f(a)+ f(b) = 0 \iff f(a) = - f(b)$
$\iff \log_{10} a + 3^a - 3^{\frac1a} = - \log_{10}b - 3^b + 3^{\frac1b}$
$\iff \log_{10} a + 3^a - 3^{\frac1a} = \log_{10}\frac1b + 3^{\frac1b} - 3^{\frac{1}{1/b}}$
$f'(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0 \implies a = \frac1b$
$\implies x^2 -2x + 2 = 2|x-m| + 1$
$\iff (x - 1)^2 = 2 |x - m|$
At this point, I'm stuck. I tried expanding the absolute value signs, but the unidentified $m$ in each domain makes it difficult to deal with. Please advise!

Formatting note:  use $\log$ rather than $log$

@J.W.Tanner Thank you! I just updated the post.

check out https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rduyqg0rja. - you want a symmetric interval about $m=1$ , get endpoints by finding where the derivative of the parabola is $\pm2$

@WW1 Thank you very much! That makes a lot of sense! I was able to get 3 values of m as the answer using your approach.

Hint: At this point, you can try casework using the definition of absolute value.
You have to consider $$x-m = \dfrac{1}{2}(x-1)^2$$ and $$x-m =- \dfrac{1}{2}(x-1)^2$$
This will generate four roots and then you need to determine the value of $m$ that reduces those to three.
You will find three solutions $$m = \dfrac{1}{2}, 1, \dfrac{3}{2}$$
The nice interactive Desmos plot by @WW1 can graphically show the three $(x,y)$ values for each of the three $m's$ we found.

Hi, thank you! It seems you missed the other 2 values of m where the lines are tangent to the curve.

You are correct, doing problems right before bed is not a good idea - Added an update with three values. Regards
